# How can I see the main package for a given program in Centos 8

Tags: centos, package-management, locate

I want to know which exact installed package that allows a program to run, I used `locate <program_name>` command, but that seems to throw all related files a directories that contains that `program_name`. Is there a better way in Centos8 to list only that package responsible for that program?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find out which package provides a specific binary using `rpm -q --whatprovides`:

```
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/ls
coreutils-single-8.30-8.el8.x86_64
```

To determine the binary providing a given command, use `command -v`:

```
$ command -v ls
/usr/bin/ls
```

Comment: Yes, it does what I need. Thanks